# get menuitem in oncreate or onresume

Tags: android, menuitem

I need disable menu item on specific function and i have tried with some code like:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    Menu menu;
```

then assign here

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    return true;
}
```

Then later use assigned Menu object to get required items

```
menu.findItem(R.id.avviapc).setEnabled(false);
```

or:

```
MenuItem avviopc;

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.right_home, menu);
        avviopc = menu.getItem(R.id.avviapc);
        return true;
    }

avviopc.setEnabled(false);
```

But i have alway crash:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2131296295, Size: 3
                      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.getItem(MenuBuilder.java:741)
```

or:

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference
```

I call: `menu.findItem(R.id.avviapc).setEnabled(false);` onCreate or onResume if specific value in if is true.

If call after 2/3 second after activity start with manual button the code work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu is called after oncreate and onresume =)

Answer (score 0):

MenuItem.getItem(index) take index of the menu item.  If you want to take the id to reference the item use MenuItem.findItem:

avviopc= menu.findItem(R.id.avviapc); //item id

avviopc= menu.getItem(indexOfavviopc); //item index

Comment: The problem is not this as you can see from the code I use different alternatives, the problem is always the same: Try to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem (int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Call your method in `onCreateOptionsMenu` to solve the index error:

```
avviopc= menu.findItem(R.id.avviapc); // Do not use  getItem(position)
```

But if you also know the position of your menu item lets say they are three and you want the third one then:

```
avviopc = menu.getItem(2);
```

**Description:**
`getItem(int)` wants a position of the menu item for that menu.
`findItem(int)` wants the resource `id` of the menu item.

Comment: The problem is not this as you can see from the code I use different alternatives, the problem is always the same: Try to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem (int)' on a null object reference

Comment: When a menu is inflated already nothing will be null. Try check some where else. I believe there may be somewhere an error arises.

Comment: Menu inflated always next oncreate and onresume, but i call the menu in onresume and it is null... You did not understand the problem then.

Comment: 07-18 18:29:21.629  20183-20183/? I/onCreate:
07-18 18:29:21.719  20183-20183/? I/onStart: 
07-18 18:29:21.719  20183-20183/? I/onResume: 
07-18 18:29:21.739  20183-20183/? I/onCreateOptionsMenu:

Comment: Array `IndexOutOfBoundsException` I am sure thats how it is called